# Resource files not found when running JUnit test

Tags: java, maven, junit

I'm having trouble running my JUnit test, it fails because it is not able to find the projects resources.

My test starts a server which loads all the needed resources using an URLClassLoader. I have no problem with the resources not being found when running my project otherwise. This problem only occurs when I try to run my JUnit test.

I have tried adding the file paths as arguments in my runtime configuration for the test like this, ex:

```
-cp .:/path/to/the/config/file
```

But it makes no difference.

Help please!

**Project structure:**
[image]

Comment: How are you running the JUnit tests?  In an IDE or with something like gradle or maven?

Comment: Hi, I run my test as a JUnit 4 test in Eclipse

Comment: Show your launcher configuration and your project structure.

Comment: I'm very new to JUnit testing, my project is a maven project. Maybe I need to define what files to be used for the test in my pom file as well?

Comment: If your test path is not `src/test/java`, you need to define it in `pom.xml` with tag `<testSourceDirectory>` inside `<build>` tag. And you need maven-surefire-plugin, too.

Comment: @bigdestroyer, thank you my test path was not in src/test/java, moved ut there and it is now working! :D. Add an answer so I can accept it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Default Maven test path is `src/test/java`, so if your tests are not in that directory, you have to define your test path in `pom.xml` with tag `<testSourceDirectory>`, inside `<build>`. You have to include `maven-surefire-plugin`, too.

Comment: I advise against changing the `testSourceDirectory` unless you know what you're doing **and** you have a very good reason :-)

Comment: For what reason? For instance, I don't like tipical source/test directory `src/main/java`/`src/test/java`. In all my projects, I change the `<testSourceDirectory>` and `<sourceDirectory>` value to `${project.basedir}/test` and `${project.basedir}/src`. I think it is prettier and cleaner.

Comment: It's confusing for people who are used to Maven and it will get you in trouble when you start adding more languages and plugins (`src/main/webapp`, `src/main/site`, `src/main/scala`, ...). Also resource processing gets more complicated if you merge the resource and source folders. See http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html

Answer (score 1):

The convention in Maven is to have all Java test code in `src/test/java`. This is to prevent accidental inclusion of test code in the final product. So I suggest you move your tests.

Since you don't show the code which you use to load the resource, I can't tell you whether there are any bugs in that. But `/path/to/the/config/file` is most likely wrong; is must be `/path/to/the/config` so you can say in Java `getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("file")`.

But I suggest to use a command line argument to specify the config file:

```
main(String[] args) {
    File configFile = new File(args[0]).getAbsoluteFile();
    if(!configFile.exists()) throw new IllegalArgumentException("Unable to find config file: " + configFile);
    ...
}
```

That makes error handling much more simple. Also, it allows to use different config files in tests and later in production.